# Calling fast C Mersenne Twister implementation (SFMT) from Python

Tags: random, python-c-api, mersenne-twister

I'm trying to call the SFMT Mersenne Twister implementation (found at http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/SFMT/) from Python. I'm doing this because I'd like to be able to quickly sample from a discrete pdf with 4 probabilities. I'm writing some simulations and this is by far the slowest part of my code.

I've managed to write some C code which works, and samples the input PDF using a random number in [0,1] created with the SFMT algorithm.

However *I don't know how to initialise the SFMT random number generator properly when calling from Python*. I only want to initialise it once of course, and then I need to pass the address of the struct used to intialise it (`sfmt`) into my calls to `sfmt_genrand_real1`.

So some example code would be:

```
// Create a struct which stores the Mersenne Twister's state
sfmt_t sfmt;

// Initialise the MT with a random seed from the system time
// NOTE: Only want to do this once
int seed = time(NULL);
sfmt_init_gen_rand(&sfmt, seed);

// Get a random number
double random_number = sfmt_genrand_real1(&sfmt);
```

The problem is that I don't know how to only seed the SFMT random number generator once when calling this code from Python. If I were just writing everything in C, I'd do the intialisation in the main() function, then pass the `&sfmt` argument to all subsequent `sfmt_genrand_real1()` calls.

But because I'm compiling this C code, then calling it from Python, I can't initialise that variable once. For now, I've stuck the initialisation right before the `sfmt_genrand_real1()` call, because it's the only way I could get the code to even compile and be able to access the `sfmt` variable in the call to the random number generator. All my attempts to somehow make the `sfmt` variable "global" backfired.

So my question is: **is there a way to initialise the C SFMT random number generator only once, then access the `sfmt` struct use for that initialisation in all my subsequent calls to `c_random_sample` from Python?**

Many thanks in advance to anyone who can help with this.

Here's my C code in full. (To compile you'd need to have all the SMFT `.c` and `.h` files in the same folder, then compile using `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`)

```
#include "Python.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "SFMT.h"


static double*
get_double_array(PyObject* data)
{
    int i, size;
    double* out;
    PyObject* seq;

    seq = PySequence_Fast(data, "expected a sequence");
    if (!seq)
        return NULL;

    size = PySequence_Size(seq);
    if (size < 0)
        return NULL;

    out = (double*) PyMem_Malloc(size * sizeof(double));
    if (!out) {
        Py_DECREF(seq);
        PyErr_NoMemory();
        return NULL;
    }

    for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
        out[i] = PyFloat_AsDouble(PySequence_Fast_GET_ITEM(seq, i));
    }

    Py_DECREF(seq);

    if (PyErr_Occurred()) {
        PyMem_Free(out);
        out = NULL;
    }

    return out;
}


static PyObject*
c_random_sample(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    int i;
    double* pdf;

    PyObject* pdf_in;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O:c_random_sample", &pdf_in))
        return NULL;

    pdf = get_double_array(pdf_in);
    if (!pdf)
        return NULL;

    // Create a struct which stores the Mersenne Twister's state
    sfmt_t sfmt;
    int seed = time(NULL);

    // Initialise the MT with a random seed from the system time
    sfmt_init_gen_rand(&sfmt, seed);
    // NOTE: This simply re-initialises the random number generator
    // on every call. We need to only initialise it once...

    double r = sfmt_genrand_real1(&sfmt);
    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        r -= pdf[i];
        if (r < 0) {
            break;
        }
     }
     PyMem_Free(pdf);
     return PyInt_FromLong(i);
}


static PyMethodDef functions[] = {
    {"c_random_sample", c_random_sample, METH_VARARGS},
    {NULL, NULL}
};


PyMODINIT_FUNC initc_random_sample(void)
{
    Py_InitModule4(
        "c_random_sample", functions, "Trying to implement random number sampling in C", NULL, PYTHON_API_VERSION
    );
}
```

Comment: That kind of PRNG is probably still much slower than newer ones (PCG, xoroshiro and co.). Those are even available in python (through external libs). But much more important: maybe you should have shown your code first to reason about this performance. I can imagine some reasons apart from the PRNG on the source of that slowness.

Comment: Thanks for your reply sascha. I'm writing a simulator which needs to sample random numbers from distributions which are dependent on the current state of the system. So I can't easily cache samples in advance. Essentially Python is too slow for what I'm after, which is why I turned to C. Nevertheless I'll have a look at those PRNGs you mention, thank you.

Comment: I just did a quick test of SFMT vs PCG. SFMT seems to be a about twice as quick to create 1 billion uint32_t random numbers.

Comment: Although the speed tests at http://xoroshiro.di.unimi.it/ seem to suggest it can be quick. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Thanks for pointing those out to me sascha. I have managed to get over my initialisation issue by defining a Python class in C, and initialising the random number generator in my class's constructor.

Comment: I see. I expected somewhat a wrong-usage of discrete-sampling (paying for the setup each time if for example O(1) sampling is used). But i see now, that your case is highly dynamic, which changes a lot. Keep in mind, that Python's PRNG-implementation within core + numpy is C-code too. But it's certainly not wrong to trust your benchmarks if done correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`sfmt` goes at the global scope in C:

```
static sfmt_t sfmt; /* outside any functions */
```

The initialization goes in your module `init` function - this is called once, when the module is first imported into Python:

```
PyMODINIT_FUNC initc_random_sample(void)
{
    /* Py_InitModule4 to initialize the module as before */ 

    int seed = time(NULL);
    sfmt_init_gen_rand(&sfmt, seed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you are looking for, but if you don't mind the dependencies (mainly Numpy and Cython), you may find useful the [ng-numpy-randomstate](https://github.com/bashtage/ng-numpy-randomstate) library which contains many fast random number generators (in particular dSFMT).

If you can use it, it will save you the work of writing the C wrappers.

Also, this module (or some features at least?) might get merged in Numpy in the future (cf. Numpy open issue [#6967](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6967)).